# Cyrillic fonts in XeLateX beamer document

Tags: beamer, xetex

I'm MikTeX user and i'm new with beamer/XeLaTeX. There I got template of presentation(btw, be careful: if you don't load `sourceserifpro`;`sourcesanspro`;
`sourcecodepro` packages, it will not compile). I find this beautiful so I tried to install it. I placed it in C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex . Then i tried to compile sample.tex and ran into problem.

https://github.com/FuzzyWuzzie/Beamer-Theme-Execushares .

1. I tried to make cyrillic font in this document two ways: Firstly I
   added `[russian]babel` but it change nothing, cyryllik letters still
   was invisible.
2. Secondly I changed those lines in `beamerthemeExecushares.sty` to
       Times New Roman. In that cases instead of nothing I got squares in
       place of letters. It was better than nothing but still unnaceptable.

%\usepackage{sourceserifpro}

%\usepackage{sourcesanspro}

%\usepackage{sourcecodepro}

- So how I can make cyrillik letters in this document?
- And why those commands work with % symbol?

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working code, with your preamble?

Comment: Oh, i forgot to write - i tried to compile sample.tex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, with a fresh mind, i found the solution:need just determine fonts with commands in the preamble, then document will compile fine.

```
\setmainfont{Times New Roman} 
\setsansfont{Source Sans Pro}
\setmonofont{Courier New}
```

[image]